# Why jQuery submit is not sending data filled with ng-value to server side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a form with some hidden inputs, I have some options inside the form (ul-li's) and ng-click for each li, like the following code:

```
<form>
<input type="hidden" id="actionToDoInput" name="action" ng-value="actionToDo"/>
<ul>
<li ng-click="submitForm($event)" data-action="DO_THIS_ACTION1">Submit this form!</li>
<li ng-click="submitForm($event)" data-action="DO_THIS_ACTION2">Submit this form!</li>
<li ng-click="submitForm($event)" data-action="DO_THIS_ACTION3">Submit this form!</li>


...
</ul>
</form>
```

In the Angular+jQuery side:

```
...
$scope.actionToDo = "";
$scope.submitForm = submitForm;
function submitForm(event){
   $this = $(event.currentTarget); // li
   $scope.actionToDo = $this.data('action');
   $this.closest('form').submit();
}
```

Then in the server side, the value of action is null, when I'm waiting the value of the actionToDo, but if I set the value of the actionToDoInput via jQuery it works:

```
$this.closest('form').find('#actionToDoInput').val( $this.data('action') );
```

I believe this is due to the mix of Angular and jQuery, because if I open the browser inspector I can see that the angular code works fine, simply the .submit() doesn't send the data to the server side.

How can I get it works without jquery submit?

Comment: Can you paste the server-code associated with this as well? :)

Comment: <?php print_r( $_POST ); ?>

Comment: Did you define the form method as "POST" and your back-end path as action?

Comment: Doesn't make sense using jQuery for this at all